# download by wget without specific folder site

Tags: wget, downloading-website-files

how download site for  viewing offline without specific folder
for example i want download the site without http://site.com/forum/ sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

```
wget --help
```

might lead you to

```
-nH, --no-host-directories      don't create host directories.
```

I'd try that first, but I'm not sure whether it will do what you want.